# MVC - JS alert message in the wrong encoding

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I don't have a problem and I can't figure out how to fix if

```
var answer = confirm("@Html.Raw(Res.MyMsg)");
```

in the polish version of that file in the `MyMsg` iI have a letter `ó` but I get `&#243;`.

I have that tag in my page

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and also the resources file which contains the `MyMsg` property is also encoded with `UTF-8` (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`). So, what's wrong ?

### Edit

ok, that code solves the encoding problem

```
var answer = confirm('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Res.MyMsg))');
```

but there are quotes around that message

### Edit2

I had to put that code without quotes:

```
var answer = confirm(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Res.MyMsg)));
```

and now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Javascript strings don't use html character entities.  (it's javascript not html)  So outputting the message in HTML encoding is incorrect.  It needs to be formatted as a javascript string.